# Altering Content in Multiple Views based on User Input [xCode/iOS]

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, storyboard, automatic-ref-counting

This is probably rather simple, but I'm having difficulties getting my head around it. The basic premise for the app that I'm creating involves having a TableView which lists a bunch of topics. The user selects one of these, a TabBarController is pushed, and I intend to have the content inside of these sub-views change based on that original selection.

I've looked around for a way to do it properly, but can't seem to find anything that adresses how I might go about pushing the content to these views. Initially, I was using a ViewController with a SegmentedSelection element. Basically, I would use the title from the Controller, which it would automatically inherit from the TableView selection, format it, and make this form the basis for the links to the relevant content i.e. I would have an imageview that would load a file .png. Obviously this is no where near as User Friendly as using the native UITabBarController.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

PS: I'm using StoryBoards and ARC.

Comment: How is all of the data that's populating the table being stored? Are you pulling from a database or an array, or what? If you use a custom data class, you can add an id property that you can use to match up all of the data.

Comment: I'm using an array as the datasource for the table, so are you suggesting there would be a way to pass an associated ID to all the view controllers which are 'children' of the tab bar controller?

Comment: Yes. Do you already know the order of all of the objects in your array?

Comment: Yeah, its a text based array that written in-line. By the way, I really appreciate the help, iOS is proving very difficult to get my head around.

Comment: I posted code as an answer, because I can't format code in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you in the view controller that you're going to when you call `pushViewController`, you need to create a custom `init` method. Something like `initWithId:(NSUInteger *)rowID`. Make sure you declare it in the header file. Then in your first view controller with the table, when you initialize the viewController (and set the delegate) that you're going to, you would call your custom `init` method instead of just `init` and pass `[myArray objectAtIndex:selectedRowThatsAnNSUinteger]`. Instead of passing the row #, you could also just pass the whole array if you want. If you do that, make sure to change the custom init method to match the change. Now, in your view controller's new `init` method, you can take what's being given to it in the method and do some sort of check on the number that was passed (since you know the row #). Hope that was helpful.